# Is $Q = \{q\in\mathcal{U}_q \mid q^T\tilde{M}q <2\}$ with $\tilde{M}\succ 0$ convex set?

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, positive-definite

I am reading [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1109/ACC.2011.5991284), which says that set

$$Q = \left\{q \in \mathcal{U}_q \mid q^T \tilde{M} q < 2 \right\}$$

is convex, where

1. $\mathcal{U}_q$ is a set of **unit quaternions**, i.e.,  $q^Tq=1$.
2. $\tilde{M}\succ0$, i.e., positive definite.

I have the trouble to show that $Q$ is convex.

Suppose $q_1, \, q_2 \in Q$, consider $0\leq\alpha\leq 1$ and
\begin{align*}
&[\alpha q_1+(1-\alpha)q_2]^T\tilde{M}[\alpha q_1+(1-\alpha)q_2]\\
\rightarrow\, &\alpha^2q_1^T\tilde{M}q_1 + (1-\alpha)^2q_2^T\tilde{M}q_2 + 2\alpha(1-\alpha)q_1^T\tilde{M}q_2
\end{align*}

I believe the sum of first two terms is less than $2$. However, how to confirm the third term?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality constraint is convex (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/526657/show-convexity-of-the-quadratic-function/526678)). However, the set $Q$ is not convex since the set $\mathcal{U}_q$ is not convex. Reference [13] of the article discusses this nonconvexity issue.