# Show that the function $f(\vec{x})=\frac{1}{2}\vec{x}^TG\vec{x}+\vec{x}\vec{c}$ is convex if and only if $G$ is semidefinited positive.

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

Show that the function $f(\vec{x})=\frac{1}{2}\vec{x}^TG\vec{x}+\vec{x}\vec{c}$ is convex if and only if $G$ is semidefinited positive.

My approach:

$\Rightarrow]$

I want to show that $\vec{x}^TG\vec{x}>0 \quad$ for any $\quad \vec{x}\neq \vec{0}$

Since $f(\vec{x})$ is convex then $f(\vec{x})+\nabla f(\vec{x})(\vec{y}-\vec{x})\leq f(\vec{y})$ for every $\vec{x},\vec{y}\in C$ (domain of $f$)

Then I end up with the following inequality: $$0\leq -\frac{1}{2}\vec{x}^TG\vec{x} + \vec{x}^TG^T\vec{x}+\frac{1}{2}\vec{y}^TG\vec{y}- \vec{x}^TG^T\vec{y}$$

Then $$0\leq \frac{1}{2}(\vec{y}-\vec{x})^TG(\vec{x}+\vec{y})+ \vec{x}^TG^T(\vec{x}-\vec{y})$$

I'm not sure if my approach is correct. Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: I’d use the familiar convexity condition $f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \leq \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(y)$ to conclude that $\lambda(1-\lambda)(x-y)^TG(x-y)\geq 0$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/526657/show-convexity-of-the-quadratic-function

Comment: take the inequality but exchange x and y, then add. Or: second derivative test

Comment: you can transform the inequality  to $\frac12 (x-y)^T G(x-y)\ge0$.

Comment: Thanks! @daw What would be the transformation? I can't see where the $G^T$ goes.

Comment: You can replace $G$ by $(G+G^T)/2$ without changing the function $f$. So you can suppose $G$ is symmetric

Comment: @daw Thanks! It is valid to say that $x^TG^Tx=x^TGx$? (Since it's a scalar)